# Instrumenting memory IO in C/C++ for hardware emulation

Tags: c++, c, instrumentation, emulation

**Ok, some background on what and why?**

I want to compile and run microcontroller firmware (bare metal, no OS) on desktop linux. I don’t want to write a bytecode interpreter or binary translator; I want to compile the original source. Running a FW as standard GUI application has lot of advantages like quick dev iterations, advanced debugging, automated testing, stress testing, etc.. I've done this before with AVR microcontrollers for a few projects and usually took the following steps:

- provide HW related headers not existing on desktop (mostly MMIO register definitions -> global variables)
- implement peripheral emulation code (lcd, eeprom)
- do some GUI that reflects the original device's user interface (lcd, buttons)
- glue everything together

The first 3 steps is easy (and not much code for AVR's), the last one is tricky. Some constructs in FW end up as infinite loops in the desktop version (eg. busy loop waiting on peripheral register change, or memory change by interrupt handlers), others end up as no op (writing into MMIO which on the real system trigger something), and fusing the FW's main loop with the GUI lib's main loop needs some creativity too. If the FW is nicely layered then low level code can be substituted with glue functions without hacking too much.

Though the overall behavior is impacted by these changes, I found the end result very useful in many cases. Unfortunately this method is intrusive (FW modification), and glue logic is highly dependent on the architecture of the FW (needs to be reinvented every time).

**Getting closer to the question...**

From C/C++ point of view the most important difference between the FW and the code running on a proper OS is MMIO. MMIO access has side effects, different side effects for reading and writing. In a desktop app this concept does not exist (unless you poke HW from userspace). If it would be possible to define a hook when a memory location is read or written, that would enable proper peripheral emulation and FW could be compiled mostly intact. Of course this cannot be done in C++, the whole purpose of a native language is against this. But the same concept (tracking memory access runtime) is used by memory debuggers with the help of instrumentation.

*I have a few ideas on implementation, so my question is how feasible do you think they are, or is there any other way the achieve the same result?*

1. No instrumentation at all. x86 can signal if a memory location is accessed and it is used by debuggers to implement watchpoints (break on memory access). As a proof of concept I created this test program:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   volatile int UDR;

   void read()  { printf("UDR read\n"); }
   void write() { printf("UDR write\n"); }

   int main()
   {
       UDR=1;
       printf("%i\n", UDR);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   UDR is the MMIO register I want to track, and if I run the compiled program under GDB with the following script:

   ```
   watch UDR
   commands
   call write()
   cont
   end

   rwatch UDR
   commands
   call read()
   cont
   end
   ```

   The result is exactly what I want:

   ```
   UDR write
   UDR read
   1
   ```

   The problem is that I don’t know if this scalable at all. As far as I know watchpoints are a limited HW resource, but couldn’t find out the limit on x86. I would probably need less than 100. GDB also supports software watchpoints, but only for writing, so it’s not really usable for this purpose. Another downside that the code would only run under a GDB session.
2. Runtime instrumentation. If I’m correct Valgrind/libvex does this: reads the compiled binary and inserts instrumentation code at memory access locations (among many others). I could write new Valgrind tool that is configured with addresses and callbacks as the above GDB script, and execute the application a Valgrind session. Do you think this is feasible? I found some documentation on new tool creation but it doesn’t seem to be an easy ride.
3. Compile time instrumentation. Memory and Address sanitizers in clang and gcc are working this way. It's a 2 part game, the compiler emits instrumented code and a sanitizer library (implementing the actual checks) is linked to the application. My idea is to replace the sanitizer library with an own implementation that performs the above callbacks, without doing any compiler modification (which is probably beyond my capabilities). Unfortunately I didn't find much documentation on how the instrumented code and the sanitizer library interacts, I only found papers describing the checker algorithms.

So that's all for my problem, any comment on any topic is appreciated. :)

Comment: Pick a language. C is not C++. In particular, C++ classes allow you to overload operators. `UDR=1` can call `MMIO_t::operator=(int)`.

Comment: I have never used such a simulator, but instead use JTAG debugging on actual, real hardware.  The number of 'works on simulator but not on device' posts are impressive...

Comment: For one device I have C firmware, for the other I have C++11. MMIO registers are simple uint8_t, uint16_t volatile global variables (with fixed address in FW) handling of these with instrumentation would be language independent. 
Defining a custom type for MMIO's and defining op=() for this type is a good idea, I didn't think of it. But it only allows catching the writes, for busy waiting loops I need to catch reads too. Anyway I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I have JTAG and I use it in normal development. It's a bit clumsy, having my laptop, the JTAG, the target board, and bench power supply connected to each other with a bunch of cables, but that's ok for a fixed workbench. I would like to have a development option on the go. And as I said desktop debugging and testing capabilities are magnitudes better than what JTAG provides. I'm also aware of the fact that emulation/simulation is not the real thing, and it's not the goal of this experiment either.

Comment: OK, I have to admit that my office has a few cables... OK, so many that I don't go under the benches because something micht fall out and I may never get it working again, (also, there are things living under there that I don't want to meet:).   JTAG gives me source-level breakpoints and stepping, stack, register, variable and memory inspection - I can live with that.

Comment: "Of course this cannot be done in C++" - of course it can't be done in **standard** C++. Specific platforms may have ways to do it.

Comment: @GyorgySzekely: You can catch reads by `MMIO_t::operator int`.

Comment: @MSalters: oh that's good. Also, I need to revise my C++ knowledge. :)

Comment: (Just throwing out ideas...)  I've been building firmware using http://www.state-machine.com/ stuff to build emulated systems based on hierarchical state machines and simulated hardware events.  With event queues and run-to-completion task semantics it's reasonably straightforward build emulations that behave like the real hardware with exact fidelity.  Porting to bare-metal with no OS or even a task scheduler is easy and preferable in most cases.  There is a "per-product" license fee, but for our products it has been well worth it to have proven code long before the board is even taped-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got time to reply to ALL of the questions in your question, but this is probably going to be too long to be a comment...

So regarding "watch points" in the debugger, they use debug registers, and whilst you can write code to use those registers yourself (there are API functions to do that - you need to be in kernel mode to write to these registers), as you state yourself, you will run out of registers. The number is MUCH lower than your 100 as well. In x86 processors there are 4 debug location registers, that cover reads and/or writes to a 1-8 byte wide location. So, it would work if you have a total of less than 32 bytes of IO space (that are spread over no more than 4 chunks of no more 8 bytes each).

Option 2 has the problem that you need to guarantee that the region used by your IO registers is not used for something else in your application. This may be "easy", if all the IO registers are, say, in the first 64KB. Otherwise, you have to try to figure out if it's a MMIO access or a regular access. As well as writing your own version of Valgrind is not something you instantly get done... Even if you hire the guy that wrote valgrind in the first place...

Option 3 has the same problem as option 2 with regard to matching addresses. My feeling is that this won't help you that much, and you are better off approaching it in a different way.

The approach that I have seen in various chip simulators that I have used is to modify the access to the real hardware into a function call. You could do that in C++ by something like the method MSalters describes.

Or by modifying your code, such that you do:

```
MMIO_WRITE(UDR, 1);
```

and then let the `MMIO_WRITE` translate to:

```
 #if REAL_HW
 MMIO_WRITE(x, y)   x = y
 #else
 MMIO_WRITE(x, y)  do_mmio_write(x, y)
 #endif
```

where `do_mmio_write` is able to understand addresses and what they do in some way.

This is certainly how the GPU model that I use at work for modelling the latest and greatest GPU we're about to make into silicon, and was the model used by the previous company I worked for that had such a model.

And yes, you will have to rewrite some of your code - ideally your code is written such that you have specific small sections of code that touch the actual hardware [this is certainly good practice if you ever want to move from one type of microcontroller to another, since you would otherwise have to do a lot more rewriting in such a case too].

As Martin James points out, the problem with any such simulation is that if your actual simulator isn't VERY good, you run into "compatibility problems" - in particular things like hardware vs software race conditions, where your software is perfectly synchronous to the simulated hardware model, but the real hardware will do things asynchronously to the software, so your two reads of two registers will now get different values than the software model, because some arbitrary thing changed in the real hardware that your software model didn't take into account - and now you have one of those nasty bugs that only occur once in a blue moon, and only on the "can't debug" hardware variant, never in the software model.

Comment: For locating the MMIO registers I was thinking of using the symbol table as GDB does, instead of pinning down the MMIO range (both option 2 and 3 tools should be able to access it).
Your macro based proposal looks promising to me. Originally I aimed for no FW source modification, but including macros that expand to noop in FW is acceptable. I like it better than involving the C++ typesystem as MSalters suggested.
+1 for the info on debugger limits.

Comment: As for the sim<->real incompatibilities, I'm aware of those. I wrote peripheral emulation on purpose (instead of simulation), there's no device model, or accurate timing at all. My goal with all of this for example is to test drive an AT command set parser with a large data set in (more or less) its original context, as part of the integration process. The emphasis is on test automation and higher level functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments by MSalters and the answer by Mats I clearly over complicated the topic. Since I have access to the source there are language level features for hooking MMIO operations easier than using instrumentation. I evaluated the versions proposed with a minimalist serial echo example:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void mainloop(volatile uint8_t* reg) {
    while(1) {
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, RXC);
        uint8_t tmp = *reg;
        *reg = tmp+1;
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA,  TXC);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    UCSRB = _BV(RXEN) | _BV(TXEN);  // enable UART rx/tx
    UBRRL = 12;                     // 12: 38400 @8Mhz 0.2% error

    mainloop(&UDR);
}
```

It receives a byte on the serial port and transmits the byte incremented by one. It has the common MMIO register use cases including passing the register pointer to a function.

### The C way

In this case all MMIO access is wrapped with macros which end up being no-op for production code, but call into hook functions in emulation. A register is mmio8_t which is a non-integral type, so forgetting to put the macro in place will result in a compile time error.

```
#if 0   // this is the Production mode
#include <avr/io.h>

//MMIO macros are no op in production
#define MMIO_READ(mmio_reg) mmio_reg
#define MMIO_WRITE(mmio_reg, data) mmio_reg=data

typedef volatile uint8_t mmio8_t;
#endif

#if 1   // this is the Emulation mode
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// register bit definitions for UCSRA and UCSRB skipped to shorten code sample

struct st_mmio8 {
    const char * name;
    // uint8_t value;
    // emulation hooks for the register
};
typedef const struct st_mmio8 mmio8_t;

mmio8_t UCSRA = { "UCSRA" };    //these are THE mmio registers
mmio8_t UCSRB = { "UCSRB" };
mmio8_t UBRRL = { "UBRRL" };
mmio8_t UDR = { "UDR" };

// some bit magic taken from <avr/io.h>
#define _BV(bit) (1 << (bit))
#define bit_is_set(sfr, bit) (MMIO_READ(sfr) & _BV(bit))
#define loop_until_bit_is_set(sfr, bit) do { } while (bit_is_clear(sfr, bit))

uint8_t MMIO_READ(mmio8_t addr) {
    printf("MMIO_READ id: %s\n", addr.name);
    return _BV(RXC) | _BV(TXC);
}

void MMIO_WRITE(mmio8_t addr, uint8_t val) {
    printf("MMIO_WRITE id: %s\n", addr.name);
}
#endif

void mainloop(mmio8_t* reg) {
    while(1)     {
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, RXC);
        uint8_t tmp = MMIO_READ(*reg);
        MMIO_WRITE(*reg, tmp+1);
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA,  TXC);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    MMIO_WRITE(UCSRB, _BV(RXEN) | _BV(TXEN));  // enable UART rx/tx
    MMIO_WRITE(UBRRL, 12);                     // 12: 38400 @8Mhz 0.2% error

    mainloop(&UDR);
}
```

The MMIO access is correctly hooked, but the readability of the code is decreased, epsecially if someone is used to the original style.

### C++ style

This option relies on the C++ operator overloading. An mmio_t class is defined with type converting assignment operator to hook writes, and a cast operator to hook reads:

```
#if 0   // this is the Production mode
#include <avr/io.h>
using mmio8_t = volatile uint8_t;
#endif

#if 0   // this is the Emulation mode
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// register bit definitions for UCSRA and UCSRB skipped to shorten code sample

// some bit magic taken from <avr/io.h>
#define _BV(bit) (1 << (bit))
#define bit_is_set(sfr, bit) (sfr & _BV(bit))
#define loop_until_bit_is_set(sfr, bit) do { } while (bit_is_clear(sfr, bit))

template<typename T>
class mmio_t {
    public:
    mmio_t(const std::string& regname) : regname(regname) {}

    //this is a non-chainable assignment
    void operator=(T data) {
        std::cout << "mmio_write " << regname << std::endl;
    }

    operator T() {
        std::cout << "mmio_read " << regname << std::endl;
        return _BV(TXC) | _BV(RXC);
    }
    private:
    std::string regname;
    //T value;
    //std::function hooks for emulation code
};
using mmio8_t = mmio_t<uint8_t>;

mmio8_t UCSRA("UCSRA");
mmio8_t UCSRB("UCSRB");
mmio8_t UBRRL("UBRRL");
mmio8_t UDR("UDR");

#endif

void mainloop(mmio8_t* reg) {
    while(1) {
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, RXC);
        uint8_t tmp = *reg;
        *reg = tmp+2;
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, TXC);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    UCSRB = _BV(RXEN) | _BV(TXEN);  // enable UART rx/tx
    UBRRL = 12;                     // 12: 38400 @8Mhz 0.2% error

    mainloop(&UDR);
}
```

Apart from the introduction of the mmio8_t type, the code is identical to the original and the operations a correctly captured.

While these examples are not complete or might not be 100% correct, they show the basic characteristics of each version. Thanks for all the tips and ideas!